# how to save drawable entities with leaflet.draw/draw polygons into my Postgis database with getting also the coordinates

Tags: postgis, leaflet, leaflet-draw, save

I am very new to creating webmaps with Leaflet and I am trying to save my shapes I draw into my postgis db. I would prefer to be saved as .shp or any default format (i.e. json) with its geometry field. I seek a step-by-step code like a small demo.

the script till now:

```
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(drawnItems);

    map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
        var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;
        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    });

    polygon_options = {
        allowIntersection: false,
                drawError: {
                    color: '#b00b00',
                    timeout: 1000
        },
                showArea: true,
                metric: false,
                repeatMode: false,
        shapeOptions: {
            stroke: true,
            color: '#6e83f0',
            weight: 4,
            opacity: 0.5,
            fill: true,
            fillColor: null,
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            clickable: true
        }
    }

    function drawPolygon(){
            var polygonDrawer = new L.Draw.Polygon(map, polygon_options);     
        polygonDrawer.enable();
    }
```

Comment: Could anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

So you could use draw:created to capture the layer, convert it to geojson then stringify it to save in your database. I've only done this once and it was dirty but worked.

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
  var type = e.layerType;
  var layer = e.layer;

  var shape = layer.toGeoJSON()
  var shape_for_db = JSON.stringify(shape);
});
```